# Skipping every other element in zip construction

Tags: python

I have a `for` loop over elements inside of a `zip` construction:

```
for user_vector, user in zip(sparse_matrix.transpose(), persons)
    rating = user_vector.dot(similarity_matrix)
    rating = np.array(rating.todense())[0]
    .......
```

If i want to skip every other element in iterable `a`, i do `a[::2]`, but it doesn't work for `zip` constructions.
Of course, i can set a new variable inside of the loop to handle this need, but i need a  concise solution like `[::2]`, because my code needs to be extremly readeble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip over the elements in the constituent vectors.

```
for user_vector, user in zip(sparse_matrix.transpose()[::2], persons[::2])
```

Time wise, this works out to be even better than `list(zip(...))[::2]` since you don't create those unneeded pairs in the first place. Do note that slicing still creates new copies of your data in memory.

---

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'test']

out = list(zip(x[::2], y[::2]))
print(out)
[(1, 'foo'), (3, 'baz')]
```

Comment: Now, when i am able to test that, i see, that this solution fails with `Memory error`. Array and matrix are really big, but i'am running it on server.

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav Your data has nothing to do with my answer. Open a new question and ask how you might work with big data.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ So, "works better" is only from t he side of time perfomance - not memory perfomance. From the side of memory perfomance it works worse. Please, detail this part of your answer

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav  I meant `works out better` with respect to the fact that there is no redundant data, as a pattern and design approach, not in terms of performance. No mention was made of having to work with large data, so  of course my answer was not oriented along those lines.